# How to keep import * for specific package when organizing imports in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

For some imports, I may want to keep a `*` import even I am currently using only 1-2 classes/methods.  For example, I may want to `import org.mockito.Mockito.*` even I am currently using only a few of them, because when my test grows, I will need to use more static method under `Mockito`.  However Organize Imports function in Eclipse always break down my import to import individual methods (which is the preferred behavior in most case).

Is there a way to let me control such behavior in package basis? i.e. I want to keep importing `*` for some packages (or disabling auto-break-down feature), but for other packages, I would want to use Eclipse's default behavior (deciding `*` base on number of classes/methods used)

Answer (score 12):

You can't change the policy for individual imported packages or classes, but you can set the overall threshold lower so that **Organize Imports** won't convert the wildcard import to individual ones. Go to **Preferences** > **Java** > **Code Style** > **Organize Imports** and then edit the *Number of static imports needed...* value to something small, like 2.

[image]

With it set to a small number, you can manually add a wildcard import and as long as the class uses at least the threshold number of methods, Eclipse will leave it alone.

Comment: I know about the threshold but that's why I asked this question: I want the threshold works as expected for normal cases, but I want to skip such organization (individual class/method vs *) in some case I want.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't appear to be possible at present, but as it's clearly a useful idea I've added a feature request to eclipse bugzilla for it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506826

Comment: Dear visitors, please vote for this issue on the Eclipse bugzilla using the provided link.